# FlatList react native

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I have a problem with FlatList, I can't scroll my list ...
It's block, and my list is enough fat for scrolling

```jsx
const tab_ad = [
    {"id": 0, "Price": 100000, "key": 0},
    {"id": 1, "Price": 100000, "key": 1},
    {"id": 2, "Price": 100000, "key": 2},
    {"id": 3, "Price": 100000, "key": 0},
    {"id": 4, "Price": 100000, "key": 1},
    {"id": 5, "Price": 100000, "key": 2},
    {"id": 6, "Price": 100000, "key": 0},
    {"id": 7, "Price": 100000, "key": 1},
    {"id": 8, "Price": 100000, "key": 2},   
]

export default class Event extends Component {
renderItem(item) {
        return (
            <Image source={path_default_picture} style={{width: 50, height: 50, margin: 5}}/>
        );
    }

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <FlatList
                horizontal
                data={tab_ad}
                renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
             />
         </View>
    );
}
```

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3

SomeOne can help me ?

Comment: list is not getting scroll ?

Comment: I tried your code in expo snack. It's working fine there. Just changed Image to View. https://snack.expo.io/HkcAOXLCb

Comment: I tried your code, and its working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

FlatList ignores the values that have the same key. I found that after playing a little bit. Most likely the issue is not that the scroll is not enabled but that you have similar values.

Could you please try making sure the key is unique across all the list?

If not, please make a snack with the issue

Comment: But he is using the index of the array as key.

Comment: Nice catch, didn't see that.